# How to read a resource file in Scala.js?

Tags: scala.js

Let's say I have a `map.csv` file at the same level (or some other webapp-accessible place) as `index-{dev,opt}.html`, e.g.:

```
key1,value1
key2,value2
...
keyN,valueN
```

I want to read in that CSV file and end up with a `Map[String,String]`.  I know how to do that in Scala, but how would I do that in Scala.js?

I'm trying not to hard-code the keys and values.

Answer (score 2):

The parsing is basically identical to how you would do it in conventional Scala -- it's the same language, after all.

So the real issue is *fetching* the file. There's no one-size-fits-all solution there; it depends on what you're using as the web server, for example. My own system is Play-based, and [the cognate code](https://github.com/jducoeur/Querki/blob/master/querki/scalajs/src/main/scala/querki/local/LocalizationEcot.scala#L46-L53) looks like this:

```
override def postInit() = {
  val ajaxCall:PlayAjax = controllers.Assets.versioned("messages/default/clientStrings")
  ajaxCall.callAjax().map { messageText =>
    val hoconTable = HoconParse(messageText)
    _messages = Some(MessagesImpl("", hoconTable))
    _readyPromise.complete(Success())
  }
}
```

The details there are particular to my (rather complex) setup, but the basic principle is straightforward: issue an AJAX call to load the file as text, then parse that file.

There are other options as well -- for example, loading and parsing the file server-side, and sending it to the client as strongly-typed structures using something like [Autowire](https://index.scala-lang.org/lihaoyi/autowire). It all depends on what your infrastructure looks like.

Comment: I'm working on a solution based on this.  Will let you know when I have it working.  Thanks.

Comment: So far it's not working, and I've read info that on Chrome you can't use Ajax to access a local file, so I'll have to figure out another way, I think.

Comment: Ah -- yes, local files are their own particular bundle of special, and tend to be a nuisance.