# Resources in Scala Cross-Project

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js, sbt-crossproject

I tried to use a file for a Unit test in a shared Module (https://github.com/portable-scala/sbt-crossproject)

I tried it in `src/test/resources` and `src/main/resources`

The resource was not copied to the `.jvm/target/classes` nor `.jvm/target/test-classes`

Is it not possible at all to use Resources in a shared Module or does it need a special configuration in `sbt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the idea of **francoisr** I found a workable solution.

What I did was to put the resources here:

`shared/.jvm/src/test/resources/` which is used by `sbt` for the `sharedJVM` module.

Now this runs all the tests correctly:

`sbt sharedJVM/test`

Answer (score 2):

Resources are JVM specific, and so are not supported on the JS side without using some tricks. For more on this, see [this answer by Scala.js' creator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47371523/2174693).